# strict search of string to validate month in javascript

Tags: javascript

What I'd like to do is a strict search of the months jan feb mar apr ...etc inputted into a text field formatted as

mmmyyyy (ex:jan1993).

I'd like to validate this so that the user can input either all lowercase or all uppercase (jan/JAN).

what I did doesn't seem to work.

```
     var firstM =month.charAt(0,2);
     var months = 
         {
           "jan" : "JAN",
           "feb" : "FEB",
           "mar" : "MAR",
           "apr" : "APR",
           "may" : "MAY", 
           "jun" : "JUN",
           "jul" : "JUL",
           "aug" : "AUG",
           "sep" : "SEP",
           "oct" : "OCT",
           "nov" : "NOV",
           "dec" : "DEC"
         };



 else if (firstM !== months[firstM])
        {
          errMessages += "<li class='b1'> Date of Birth must start with 3 letter month</li>\n";
          errMessages += "<li class='b2'> ex: mmmyyy / JAN1993</li>\n";
        }
```

I'm still getting use to figuring out how to utilize .charAt with the "jan" : "JAN" i figured if i did it like this, the user could input either all lowercase or all uppercase and it would validate, but the error keeps coming up no matter what i do.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The code is somehow incomplete... what does the `else` belong to?

Comment: I'd just make an array of the months in lowercase and use [.toLowerCase()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) to search and compare.

Comment: @Imp my apologies theres code inbetween that i took out for easier reading for you guys, thats why theres an else if there


And j08691 thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without regular expressions, the function might look like this:

```
function checkInput(input) {
    var months = ["jan", "feb", "mar", "apr", "may", "jun", "jul", "aug", "sep", "oct", "nov", "dec"];

    var monthPartOfInput = input.substring(0, 3).toLowerCase();                         

    if (months.indexOf(monthPartOfInput) == -1){
        // TODO: Show validation error
    }
}
```

Comment: that is the conclusion I came to, totally forgot to update this page. thanks Nick

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation, [`charAt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt) only takes one parameter and returns a string of length one.  What you are looking for is [`substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) and [`toLowerCase`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase)

```
var month = "January",
    check = month.toLowerCase().substring(0, 3);

if( months[check] ) {
   //valid month
}
```

`months[check]` will return a truthy value if the first three letters match something in your object.

Comment: should I put that into an array so i can include all months? because the user should not be allowed to put something like "FJR".

Comment: ok so i tried it out...it validates when i enter Jan1993 but not if i enter jan/JAN...what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

To simplify the code, could you use a regular expression?

```
function checkInput(input) {
   var months = /^(jan|feb|mar|apr|may|jun|jul|aug|sep|oct|nov|dec)/i;

   if (months.test(input) == false) {
    // TODO: Show validation error message
   }
}
```

Comment: unfortauntely I can't use regular expression otherwise that right there would have made life easier and cleaner lol. but thank you

Answer (score 0):

`charAt()` returns a character at specified position, not the substring, I'm not sure how you get the `month` from, but if you'd like to take the first 3 characters, use `substr`

```
var firstM = month.substr(0, 3);
```